# Unable to load the requested class: Guzzle

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am uploading a CodeIgniter project for the first time.

At localhost my website runs smoothly, but online it throws an error:

> "Unable to load the requested class: Guzzle"

This part of the code causes the problem:

```
$this->load->library('guzzle');
# guzzle client define
$client     = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

[screenshot of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tmab.png)

Comment: Welcome. Is Guzzle part of Codeigniter? Do you maybe need to `composer install`?

Comment: Thank you to look on my question... I want to **install composer** too, anyhow my **website** should run.